# How to mask email address in salesforce

Tags: visualforce

I first post pretty excited.
I have a requirement as follows. I am explaining in detail.

I have a URL say https://ap2.salesforce.com?fanID=0032800000gufvJ  in salesforce. where `Fan__c` is an custom object which has `email__c` field.
Based on this FanID I will get the email of that user.

Now I have a visualforce page with `standardcontroller="fan__c"`

```
<apex:inputText name="email>
```

In apex controller:

```
string fanid="Apexpages.currentpage().getparameter('fanID');
               if fanid != NULL
string emailaddress=[select Email from fan__c where ID=:fanID];
```

Now value in emailaddress sits in

```
<apex:InputText name=Email>
```

if the email already exists it should be replaced with asterisk as follows.
for example : assume email is  jose@gmail.com and if it exists for that particular FanID then the contents of `<apex:inputText>` should be

```
j***@g****.com
```

If email doesn't exist for that  FanID then no masking will occur. this means a new email should be created after the user hits the SAVE button.

I am literally struggling with this so any will be rewarded with points

Comment: Why don't you simply modify the email string at server side and return one with asterisks?

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the email if the query returns a value, with some regular expression.

```
String s = 'someemail@gmail.com';
System.debug(s.replaceAll('(^[^@]{3}|(?!^)\\G)[^@]', '$1*'));
```

Results with:

```
USER_DEBUG [2]|DEBUG|som********@gmail.com
```

So in your code where you've got:

```
string emailaddress=[select Email from fan__c where ID=:fanID];
```

Append the following:

```
if (Stirng.isNotBlank(emailaddress))
{
    emailaddress = emailaddress.replaceAll('(^[^@]{3}|(?!^)\\G)[^@]', '$1*');
}

return emailaddress;
```

I'll let you play with the regular expression to figure out how to mask the domain too...