# Replace substring with masking character in Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, substring

How do I replace a substring with a masking character in Visualforce? For eg. I have a list of Contacts under an Account to be displayed on the Visualforce page - email field to be masked.

`username@testcorp.com` to be displayed as `usxxxxme@testcorp.com`

I have tried left() and right() to get `us` and `me@testcorp.com` respectively. Finding it challenging to replace all intermediate characters to `x`.

Comment: Have you see this - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174468/how-to-mask-email-address-in-salesforce

Comment: Will post this comment as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this suffice? I’ll leave it up to you to define what happens if the part before the @ is 2 or less characters.

```
String valueToMask = original.substring(2, original.indexOf('@'));
String mask = 'x'.repeat(valueToMask.length());
String masked = original.replaceFirst(valueToMask, mask);
```